# React app isnt running on localhost in docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, devops

The app doesn't have a web pack though. When I make an image using a docker file and runs it. it Giving me the below logs.

I can't run my react app on localhost using docker.
Help

[image]

[image]

It Starts the server but on https://172.17.0.2 host

I want to it to running on localhost

Comment: The above are not error logs.  Can you post full logs?  Also, please share your docker file for details.

Comment: See I have updated

Comment: More logs please.